# VB.net Geckofx 45 executing jquery.hide() has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, visual-studio, geckofx

I tried the following articles [about executing javascript.](https://nhabuiduc.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/geckofx-net-webbrowser-setup-and-features/)

But the if-else statement seems not obtaining the capability of jquery.

```
     Dim jQuery As JQueryExecutor
        jQuery = New JQueryExecutor(GeckoWebBrowser1.Window)

      If (jQuery.ExecuteJQuery("typeof jQuery == 'undefined'").ToBoolean) Then
    MsgBox("no jquery here")
else
jQuery.ExecuteJQuery("$(#" + aName + ").hide();")
    end if
```

Is that something i forgotten?
The error is this one[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what is triggering the error, but it looks as if your jQuery syntax is faulty; you are selecting by an ID, which jQuery takes as a string parameter, but your `.ExecuteJQuery()` line does not include the `#` as a string.

```
jQuery.ExecuteJQuery(jQuery.ExecuteJQuery("$('#" + aName + "').hide();")
```

I know quotes can get a bit confusing, and perhaps this might be the issue?

Comment: you're right... the single quotes that i forgot. great!